# Removing LocationListener from LocationManager

Tags: android

Is it possible to remove ALL LocationListeners from the LocationManager? If yes, how?

Comment: Why don't you create an array and add your listeners to that array once you register them. At end, call removeUpdates and pass each item of array

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure if I can do this though since I create and register the listener every time I start a service. Whenever I start the service a new listener is added. I want to remove all added listeners.

Comment: @RodMichaelCoronel: "I create and register the listener every time I start a service" -- please don't. Register the listener when the service is created and unregister it when the service is destroyed.

Comment: I see... Is there a way then to change the minTime of the LocationListener I registered using the requestLocationUpdates method? This is because I detect the nearness of the user to a location and set a smaller value for the minTime. When the user goes far from the location, the minTime is set to a higher value...

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says:

Removes any current registration for location updates of the current activity with the given LocationListener. Following this call, updates will no longer occur for this listener.

[removeUpdates(LocationListener listener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates%28android.location.LocationListener%29)